# Online machine learning algorithm for complex dynamical system

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, genetic-algorithm, hidden-markov-models

I have a complex dynamical system which takes input as `x1, x2, x3` and gives output as `y1, y2, y3`. I don't have any mathematical model of the system. `x(k)` is the present input to the system and `y(k)` is the present output of the system. 
My Objective is to find `x1(k+1),x2(k+1),x3(k+1)` to maximize `y1(k+1) + y2(k+1) + y3(k+1)`. I can only access present state(k) and past state(k-1) values. 
Intuitively `y_i(k)=f(x1(k),x2(k),x3(k))` where `i=1,2,3` .
The system only take inputs s.t `a < x1,x2,x3 < b`.
Is there any online machine learning algorithm which can be applied to solve this problem?
I really appreciate any feedback.

Thanks and regards

Marcella

Comment: You appear to be looking for some kind of [Markov model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_model).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I thought some kind of neural network would be useful for this problem.

Comment: You mean dynamical system in neural network sense? (Regular dynamical system is something different)
Is something should be assigned to the edges? What is Xi ?

Comment: Xi is the input to the system. I was thinking like this , after each state I can take the output(yi(k),yi(k-1)) of the system and can calculate input for the next state xi(k+1).

Comment: @TT_ I think yi should be the input and xi should be the output of the neural net. I'm not sure though.

Comment: I use the term dynamical system to describe the behavior of the system because the system response changes with respect to time,that means the output is {10,20,30} for input {1,2,3} at time t1 and output is {11,6,15} for input {1,2,3} at time t2.

Comment: This sounds exactly like a Markov process. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_process

Comment: @Sean Owen , Thanks for the link. It helps a lot.

Comment: @Sean Owen To be a Markov process, it should be probabilities assigned to edges, no?

Comment: That might or might not describe this problem -- the problem is not specified. For example it's not clear in the description why x(k) is at all related to y(k+1). Yes you would only apply this model if the assumptions of the model are valid.

Comment: Yes, that's what I trying to get from OP: how Y depends on X. X seems to be an integer vector, but even that much is not clear. 
@marcella As is, you did not provide enough info to suggest anything useful.

Comment: @TT_ X1,X2,X3 are three inputs , which can take values within the range a and b(positive real numbers). y1,y2,y3 are three outputs depends on x1,x2 and x3. Yes x1,x2,x3 and y1,y2,y3 are all positive real numbers. x1,x2,x3 can be seen as three components of input vector X. Its a real world problem and I tried my best to describe the real-time behavior of the system. So Please let me know if you need anymore information.  Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Good link on the difference between HMM and neural networks as time series models: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25999